# iPad Corner Radius Where App Meets Status Bar

Tags: ios, ipad, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I am trying to make some custom art for my app that will be shown at the top of the app, right up against the status bar.

In order to make the art look good, I would like to know what the corner radius is for the part of the app illustrated below:

[image: What's This Corner Radius?]

I would like to know what the radius is that iOS makes your app fit into.

Thanks,

Erway Software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about `4.5`. I took a screenshot of the simulator, zoomed in about 2000% and compared various values to dial it in.

If you're making a UIView in the Interface Builder and specifying the `layer.cornerRadius` in the User Defined Runtime Attributes, a value of `5` is more than close enough.

Comment: Is that Retina? Or do I need to multiply by two for custom art?

Comment: If you're making your own art, I have no idea. I'm a programmer, not a graphic designer. But for a UIView corner radius, iOS will automatically adjust for Retina.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. When I put a screenshot into Illustrator and tried to match it, I also came out at 4.5/9px

4.5px for non-retina and 9px for retina. So yes, you have to multiply by two.